# XSL to sort bt Field1

Tags: sorting, xslt

Im in need of some help, if anyone is feeling particularly generous...
I need an XSLT to sort the XML below by Field1.  I expect it is quite simple, but I'm struggling with it.  The XML is below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://myERP.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
 <ns0:Message1>
  <ns0:MyAppRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
   <Row xmlns:ns="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
    <Field1>100</Field1>
    <Field2>11409</Field2>
    <Field3>GBA2</Field3>
    <Field4/>
    <Field5/>
    <Field6/>
    <Field8/>
    <Field7/>
   </Row>
   <Row xmlns:ns="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
    <Field1>50</Field1>
    <Field2/>
    <Field3>637281</Field3>
    <Field4>0010122587</Field4>
    <Field5>3.863</Field5>
    <Field6>KG</Field6>
    <Field8>PDISP</Field8>
    <Field7>local-LOTEND</Field7>
   </Row>
   <Row xmlns:ns="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
    <Field1>51</Field1>
    <Field2>1000041393</Field2>
    <Field3>637281</Field3>
    <Field4>0010122587</Field4>
    <Field5>3.863</Field5>
    <Field6>KG</Field6>
    <Field8>PDISP</Field8>
    <Field7>Joe.Bloggs</Field7>
   </Row>
   <Row xmlns:ns="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
    <Field1>99</Field1>
    <Field2>4</Field2>
    <Field3/>
    <Field4/>
    <Field5/>
    <Field6/>
    <Field8/>
    <Field7/>
   </Row>
  </ns0:MyAppRequest>
 </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Hoping for a solution, and thanks in advance.

My attempt, which produces no real output, is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://myERP.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://myERP.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
        <ns0:Message1>
                <ns0:MyAppRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message1/MyAppRequest/Row">
                        <xsl:sort select="Field1"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:MyAppRequest>
            </ns0:Message1>
    </ns0:Messages>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:MyAppRequest">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*I expect it is quite simple*" It probably is. Where exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm unable to get any joy with this. I guess I need to read some books. Spent 3 hours on it and I've decided to go for a workaround instead.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should post your attempt, so that we can fix it and not waste time starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is namespaces. When you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message1/MyAppRequest/Row">
```

you're not selecting anything, because `Messages`,  `Message1` and `MyAppRequest` are in a namespace and need to be addressed using a prefix bound to the corresponding namespace.

To make matters more "interesting", the author of the XML document is using the same `ns0` prefix for both `Messages` and `MyAppRequest`, even though their namespaces are different. You can see that first we have:

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://myERP.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
```

but when we get to `MyAppRequest`, the `ns0` prefix is redefined:

```
<ns0:MyAppRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
```

**How to solve this:**

You could take the easy way out and replace:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message1/MyAppRequest/Row">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Row">
```

A more efficient solution would avoid the `//` operator and list the wrapper elements explicitly, but still skirt the namespace issue by referring to them using the `*` wildcard only.

The other issue you need to heed is that the default sort order is alphabetic, while `Field1` data appears to be numeric.

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://myERP.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
        <ns0:Message1>
            <ns0:MyAppRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:Acme.com:GLOBAL:SAPERP:local:MyApp">
                    <xsl:for-each select="*/*/*/Row">
                        <xsl:sort select="Field1" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </ns0:MyAppRequest>
        </ns0:Message1>
    </ns0:Messages>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to explain and to provide a solution; very much appreciated.